# CSS Sticky Footer - With Margin

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I'm trying to apply this method of the Sticky Footer: http://code.google.com/p/cleanstickyfooter/

It works great, however, I have one problem.  The design for my particular site has a 34px margin at the top of the page.  So I've tried a few ways of implementing it, either by doing `body {margin-top:34px}` or doing `container {margin-top:34px}`.

However, in both cases, the Sticky Footer gets messed up.  When I try to compensate for the 34px, it doesn't ever seem to work out.

Any ideas?

Here's a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrZKb/

Comment: Can you show us your website or an example of the problem with your specific code?

Comment: We will be able to help better if you could post a link to your website or create a fiddle to demonstrate it.

Comment: Alright, here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrZKb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [Modern Clean CSS Sticky Footer](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/), it's working (on FireFox and IE9):

http://jsfiddle.net/jrZKb/1/

```
<body>
    <header> Header</header>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
header
{
    background-color: green;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is pretty great.  I've never seen this one before.  Works really well!

Comment: I hadn't seen it either until I googled it just then, it does look good... I think I might update my own site...